# How do I get turtle to move this square right 36 times?

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am trying to move the square to right and draw 36 squares to make a circle out of it:

```
def draw_art(x,y):
    print("Started the op")

    window = turtle.Screen()
    window.bgcolor("blue")
    print("start the drwaing")
    c =0
    brad = turtle.Turtle()
    brad.shape("turtle")
    brad.color("green")
    brad.speed(3)
    print("enter loop")
    for i in range(1,37):
        draw_square(x,y)
        brad.right(10)
        window.exitonclick()


draw_art(200,90)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you closer to what you're trying to do.  It defines the missing `draw_square()` function and then draws 36 squares in a circle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def draw_square(turtle):
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(90)

def draw_art(turtle, x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(36):
        draw_square(turtle)
        turtle.right(10)

print("Started the app")
window = Screen()
window.bgcolor('blue')

brad = Turtle()
brad.shape('turtle')
brad.color('green')
brad.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

print("Start the drawing")
draw_art(brad, 200, 90)

brad.hideturtle()

window.exitonclick()
```

[image]